# Ubuntu and windows not working.

Tags: dual-boot

My computer says "error,  no such device found grub rescue>."  how do I fix it?  I have an HP Pavillion desktop pc.  It was running Windows 7 yesterday when I selected to install some "important"  updates. After the said updates were installed,  I restated the computer as prompted.

After a while the computer just went off and said  "Bootmgr missing"  and I ran Ubuntu from an old live cd I had.  I installed Ubuntu into a 8 gb flash drive,  and downloaded a windows 7 iso since I misplaced my cd.

After downloading the iso I created a bootable usb with the iso to replace the cd I lost. I tried booting from my usb to load windows installation but it doesn't work. Now when I load up the pc it says that error message I put in the top.

As for technical experience,  I'm mostly a windows,  but I can use terminal in Ubuntu too,  as long as you directly spell out what I have to put in.

Comment: try boot-repair.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 :Before you restart to complete the update, unmount any pendrive or portable hard disk drive.

Option 2 :Use grub customizer to customize the entry.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Option 3 :Recover your boot using [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Option 4 : Fix your windows via a windows disk.[7 Bootloader](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader) until you can access windows.

I hope this will help you. :)

Comment: My friend, your a savior just for trying to help me.  Now I've seen the option of boot repair in a few different places. I'm not exactly clear on how to install it,  so if you can please tell me how to go that,  I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Open terminal and type this. 
"sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update" without quotes.

Then paste this code
"sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair"

After finish ,the Boot-Repair window will appear.

Comment: But if use ubuntu 12.04,You should use

"sudo apt-get install -y --force-yes boot-repair && boot-repair"

instead of

"sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair"